# AWS CodeDeploy failed to deploy to Windows 10 On premise machine

Tags: windows, aws-code-deploy, on-premises-instances

I am trying to deploy from S3 bucket to Windows on premise machine using AWS CodeDeploy. AWS CodeDeployAgent has been running on my Windows machine.

The error in AWS Console:

```
The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems.
```

Below is the log at `c:\ProgramData\Amazon\CodeDeploy\log\`. It is unreachable when pinging 169.254.169.254:80.

```
2019-11-15T22:40:18 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2988)]: On Premises config file does not exist or not readable
```

2019-11-15T22:40:18 ERROR [codedeploy-agent(2988)]: CodeDeploy Instance Agent Service: CodeDeploy Instance Agent Service: error during start or run: **Errno::ENETUNREACH - Failed to open TCP connection to 169.254.169.254:80 (A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network. - connect(2) for "169.254.169.254" port 80) -** C:/WINDOWS/TEMP/ocr1C29.tmp/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:882:in `rescue in block in connect'
C:/WINDOWS/TEMP/ocr1C29.tmp/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:879:in`block in connect'
C:/WINDOWS/TEMP/ocr1C29.tmp/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:91:in `block in timeout'
C:/WINDOWS/TEMP/ocr1C29.tmp/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:101:in`timeout'
C:/WINDOWS/TEMP/ocr1C29.tmp/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
C:/WINDOWS/TEMP/ocr1C29.tmp/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:863:in`do_start'
C:/WINDOWS/TEMP/ocr1C29.tmp/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
C:/WINDOWS/TEMP/ocr1C29.tmp/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:584:in`start'
C:/WINDOWS/TEMP/ocr1C29.tmp/src/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_metadata.rb:51:in `http_get'
C:/WINDOWS/TEMP/ocr1C29.tmp/src/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_metadata.rb:22:in`region'
C:/WINDOWS/TEMP/ocr1C29.tmp/src/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_poller.rb:38:in `initialize'
C:/WINDOWS/TEMP/ocr1C29.tmp/src/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/agent/base.rb:10:in`new'
C:/WINDOWS/TEMP/ocr1C29.tmp/src/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/agent/base.rb:10:in `runner'
C:/WINDOWS/TEMP/ocr1C29.tmp/src/opt/codedeploy-agent/bin/winagent.rb:42:in`block (2 levels) in service_main'
C:/WINDOWS/TEMP/ocr1C29.tmp/src/opt/codedeploy-agent/bin/winagent.rb:41:in `synchronize'
C:/WINDOWS/TEMP/ocr1C29.tmp/src/opt/codedeploy-agent/bin/winagent.rb:41:in`block in service_main'
C:/WINDOWS/TEMP/ocr1C29.tmp/src/opt/codedeploy-agent/bin/winagent.rb:89:in `with_error_handling'
C:/WINDOWS/TEMP/ocr1C29.tmp/src/opt/codedeploy-agent/bin/winagent.rb:38:in`service_main'
C:/Windows/Temp/ocr1C29.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/win32-service-0.8.10/lib/win32/daemon.rb:316:in `mainloop'
C:/Windows/Temp/ocr1C29.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/win32-service-0.8.10/lib/win32/daemon.rb:214:in`mainloop'
C:/WINDOWS/TEMP/ocr1C29.tmp/src/opt/codedeploy-agent/bin/winagent.rb:104:in `'

Answer (score 2):

I simply ran

`C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Scripts\InitializeInstance.ps1`

and the script applied the default specifications of a newborn EC2 windows instance.

for more info : [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59493723/timeout-when-trying-to-retrieve-ec2-instance-id-metadata-from-within-it)